# Automatic converting to integer while reading a file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a raw data set as .txt file as follows

```
ID    SI_Number   
1     0010
2     0005
```

I am pushing this data to postgresql using psycopg2. In the DB I am seeing the following

```
ID     SI_Number
1      10.0
2      5.0
```

In order to get rid of unwanted decimal places, I am using the following piece of code.

```
df['SI_number'] = df['SI_number'].astype(str).str.replace(r'.0$','',regex=True)
```

With this in the DB, I am seeing

```
ID    SI_Number
1      10
2      5
```

But I want to populate the ***exact*** value in the DB. Like below:

```
ID    SI_Number
1      0010
2      0005
```

I have tried `df['SI_Number'].astype(str)` but no result.

I am reading the .txt file with the following

```
df = pd.read_csv(f,usecols=col_lst,sep='|',engine='python',encoding='iso-8859-1',error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True)
```

I am using Linux OS. Also while uploading I am converting everything to VARCHAR().

Am I missing out anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert to int -> string and then apply a `zfill()` (zero fill)

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1.0, 2.0, 30.0]})

>>> df
      A
0   1.0
1   2.0
2  30.0

>>> df["A"] = df["A"].astype(int).astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.zfill(4))

>>> df
      A
0  0001
1  0002
2  0030
```

Comment: Why `zfill(4)`? It can vary. Please see my example; the second row contains three zeros whereas 1st one contains only two zero.

Comment: Don't you want to fill with zeroes? `>>> '123'.zfill(4)` => `'0123'`

Comment: Yes. However, I later realized that the string length is dynamic.